# AngularJS with MVC controller guide needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

so i started to learn about angularJS today and i also created a demo code.
Somehow the code was not run . i copy this code from somewhere and change to my name. after running the html. the code shows `{{CU.name}}` can can give a good link or simple sample code on step by step pulling data with angular Js and MVC?

```
  <script>
var TestCtrl = function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.firstCall = function () {

        $http({
            url: "@Url.Action("RetriveRecordList", "recordController")",
            dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: '',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        debugger;
        alert("haha")
        $scope.DemoList = response;
    })
       .error(function (error) {
           alert(error);
       });
}
}
```

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-init="firstCall()">

<div class="table-responsive com-table">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%">Customer ID</th>
                <th width="15%">Customer Name</th>
                <th width="15%">Email</th>
                <th width="20%">Mobile No.</th>
                <th width="25%">Address</th>
                <th width="20%">Registration Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="CU in DemoList">
                <td width="5%">{{CU.name}}</td>
                <td width="15%">{{CU.name}}</td>
                <td width="15%">{{CU.name}}</td>
                <td width="20%">{{CU.name}}</td>
                <td width="25%">{{CU.name}}</td>
                <td width="20%">{{CU.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="collapse">
        <div class="well">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `ng-app` in the html and define module in the js file. Also add commas and `:` when you define `$http` properties.

```
$http({
    url: "@Url.Action(",
    RetriveRecordList: ", ",
    recordController: ")",
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    data: '',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
```

to catch the response use `then` instead of `success`.It remove from angular version 6.1.1

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('TestCtrl',TestCtrl);

function TestCtrl($scope, $http) {
 $scope.firstCall = function() {
  $http({
    url: "@Url.Action(",
    RetriveRecordList :", ",
    recordController :")",
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    data: '',
    headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
   }).then(function(response) {
    debugger;
    alert("haha")
    $scope.DemoList = response;
   },function(error) {
    alert(error);
   }) 
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script> 

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-init="firstCall()">

<div class="table-responsive com-table">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%">Customer ID</th>
                <th width="15%">Customer Name</th>
                <th width="15%">Email</th>
                <th width="20%">Mobile No.</th>
                <th width="25%">Address</th>
                <th width="20%">Registration Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="CU in DemoList">
                <td width="5%">{{CU.name}}</td>
                <td width="15%">{{CU.name}}</td>
                <td width="15%">{{CU.name}}</td>
                <td width="20%">{{CU.name}}</td>
                <td width="25%">{{CU.name}}</td>
                <td width="20%">{{CU.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="collapse">
        <div class="well">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('ngSampleApp', []).controller('TestCtrl', `function($scope) {`

});
```

first you have to refer angular framework into you application. then define module and controller. after that in HTML file refer module name using ng-app directive.

Comment: so is a  must to define ng-app?[link]http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/show-data-in-grid-format-using-angularjs-and-web-api/  this link example does not have a ng-app also

Comment: yes every angular application must have module and its refer with html using ng-app directive